# How can I get Itunes type image interface in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Can you please suggest, what does the arrangement of image items be called in HTML terms?, I am searching in gridview and listview varieties but not able to find. [image: img]

Comment: Thanks prollygreek, I am trying to figure out the inner workings of http://masonry.desandro.com/. Sorry for any confusion caused, My Actual question how can I build the structure as in Image without using the Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is called css columns

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

```
.newspaper
{
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;
}
```

you can also try masnory plugin :

http://masonry.desandro.com/

or wookamrk plugin

https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery